# Using Colorbox.js Ajax request with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, colorbox

I hope someone can help me.

I would like to use [Colorbox.js](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) to dynamically load a Google Map when a link is clicked. So, the map doesn't need to be preloaded unless the user decides to view a larger map.

My HTML test looks as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#googlemap" id="launch_map">Check out park on Google Maps</a>
    <div id="location">
      <div class="map"></div>
    </div>


  <!-- Google Maps API -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
type="text/javascript"></script>


  <!-- Colorbox Ajax Request -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#launch_map").colorbox({
      inline: true,
      width:300,
      height:200,
      html:$("#location").html()
    });

    var googleMap = $("#cboxLoadedContent").find("div.map")[0];
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.537266, 123.250760);
    var myOptions = { zoom: 8, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(googleMap, myOptions);
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

My issue is that it doesn't load the Google map in the Colorbox. I was hoping someone can give some insight on how I can tackle this problem.

Here is a JSFilddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/xLGyQ/1/

Many thanks,
WD

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get things working without colorbox?  It doesn't seem to work regardless if colorbox is being used: http://jsfiddle.net/em6Rz/